# Where to publish supplementary math intensive material for magazine article

Tags: publications, peer-review, supporting-information

I received a review report on my magazine article (Impact Factor 7.6). Based on magazine restriction we can not use more than 3 mathematical equations. But the idea I presented in article require some mathematical evaluation as well. The reviewer suggested that we should publish relevant result and cite them in magazine article. They didn't mention whether the results should be peer reviewed or not. 
My question is for such a high impact factor (in my research area the magazine is listed as 99 percentile in JCR) magazine article is it acceptable to refer something which is not peer reviewed?
If its ok then what is best way to do so? I don't have personal website and my school don't have publicly accessible repository and arxiv accept only the full articles not just some kind of mathematical evaluation. 

 Is it fine to use researchgate to publish mathematical results?

Comment: Have you asked the editor whether your results should be peer-reviewed? (If they say "no," then, since you mention that you don't have a personal website, I would get one, and then post the supplemental material there.)

Comment: What a sad state of affairs where journals put a limit on math at *3 sad and lonely formulas for an entire article*.

Comment: @Wolfgang it's a magazine article, not a journal article. If the OP's field is like mine (where [this kind of restriction is common](http://www.comsoc.org/commag/paper-submission-guidelines)), magazine articles are very different from journal articles - they're mainly meant for introducing a piece of work to a broad audience (including non-specialists) in a friendly, non-technical and accessible way. Readers of the magazine article are then referred to the "real" publication(s) for the technical content.

Comment: @Wolfgang the limit on equations + references is largely to highlight to authors that a magazine article (in this field) is _not_ like a journal article, and shouldn't be written like one. See [What is a magazine paper and how it is different from a journal paper](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/79688/11365)

Comment: @ff524 -- ah, I had missed that distinction. My bad.

Answer (score 3):

If the main idea of the mathematical evaluation can be explained in words, then the details may not be necessary to make public, as the motivated reader can certainly rederive them.

If on the other hand the math is non-trivial, then it should be explained in a high level way, with appropriate references to the more advanced techniques used.

If the math is highly non-trivial, then that would be sufficient material for a publication in mathematics, and the full paper on the math may be posted on the arxiv.

And no, personally I wouldn't use researchgate. Researchgate is not a journal, and submissions there do not count as publications. The same applies to arxiv too, and if you have a paper-worthy mathematical result, it ought to be eventually submitted for publication.

Answer (score 1):

It's a policy, not a law, and so likely can be circumvented at least to some degree if you ask the editor. For example, if you need 6 or 7 formulas that are sufficiently simple that a typical reader would understand them, then an editor may make a reasoned exception. If you have trouble getting things down to that level, try expression some of them in terms of formulas.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about whether it should be peer-reviewed or not, but if not, a place that would be better suited to host this than ResearchGate is [FigShare](https://figshare.com/). Using FigShare, your result would actually be available without account, it would have more guarantees about remaining available, and it would actually receive a DOI.